# I can't understand how to use ffmpeg in javascript (if it's even possible)

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

Straight to the problem, I want to use ffmpeg in my javascript project for video editing. So I found cdn: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@salomvary/ffmpeg.js-umd@3.1.9001/ffmpeg-mp4.min.js"></script>` which references to "https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js", which is ffmpeg port to javascript as I understand?
I don't get any errors on import, but if I try loading ffmpeg:

```
// Initialize FFmpeg after the GAPI client is loaded
  const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });

  // // Load the FFmpeg library
  await ffmpeg.load();
```

I get error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: createFFmpeg is not defined at initializeGapiClient (index:89:18)` and it also messes my whole project. So if possible, how can I use ffmpeg in pure javascript, not Node.js. Should I download ffmpeg library files and then include them in project, I'm totally lost at this.

Comment: Did you read [the API docs](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/blob/master/docs/api.md#createffmpegoptions-ffmpeg)?

Comment: @padaleiana but this is docs for `ffmpeg.wasm` not the `ffmpeg.js` ?

Comment: I can't find any [`createFFmpeg`](https://github.com/salomvary/ffmpeg.js-umd) in that repo, nor in [this repo](https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js).

Comment: Oh, so it seems for ffmpeg.js to work I also need to use this? https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten

Comment: Or maybe there is some better method to importing ffmpeg into pure javascript project? I'm trying to make video editor in web application

Comment: https://github.com/muaz-khan/Ffmpeg.js looks promising for your application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:

```
// Initialize
const ffmpeg = FFmpeg.createFFmpeg({ log: true})
// Load
ffmpeg.load()
```

Note that I call ffmpeg in uppercase and call the method.